# RegEx: Negative lookahead with capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will capture JavaScript object properties, but I only want top level properties.
So for example I want to capture `this.nodeName` but I do not want to capture `this.nodeName.length`

I am trying the following expression: `(this\.\w+)(?!\.)`
But the lookahead seems to be only working on the `\w+` and not on the whole capture group and I don't understand why this is.
For example if I apply `this(?!\.)` to `this.` then it doesn't match `thi`, so I don't understand why capture groups seem to act differently.

[Here is a demo of my expression](https://regexr.com/717lh)

Perhaps someone more experienced in regular expression could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: You've asked for `this.` followed by one or more word characters, not followed by a `.`. `this.nodeNam` matches that description, because it starts with `this.`, then has more than one word character, and it's followed by `e`, which isn't a `.`. Try putting a `\b` at the end of the capture group, to insist it only matches at a word boundary.

Comment: You can use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): [`(this\.\w+)\b(?!\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/fcEVGR/1) the regex always "wants" to succeed, you need to force the assertion at a defined place to let the match fail, else it will backtrack to a match if any.

Comment: I might be missing something but removing negative lookahead part and leaving just `(this\.\w+)` solves the problem just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex expression:

```
const captured = 'this.party.invitation'.match(/(?<captured>this\.\w*?)(\.|\n|$)/).groups.captured
console.log(captured)
```

`?<captured>` gives a name to the group `(...)`. We use a group to capture our desired match. The regex expression also checks at the end if it ends in a dot, a new line (`\n`) or if it's the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the negative lookahead part first and then capture the following text if pattern is right. Change your regex to this,

```
(?!this\.\w+\.)(this\.\w+)
```

[Demo](https://regexr.com/717mo)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a capture group to get a match only.

In your pattern, the `\w+` allows backtracking to give up 1 character to fit in the last assertion `(?!\.)`

What you could do is first match `this.` and then assert that it is not followed by word characters and a dot.

```
\bthis\.(?!\w+\.)\w+
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `this\.` Match literally
- `(?!\w+\.)` Negative lookahead, assert that from the current position there is not 1+ word characters followed by a dot directly to the right
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3txPKm/1)